# Notation Explanation - DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is meant when someone write $d(e^{-t^2}y)$ or any kind of function for that matter inside those brackets? I read somewhere that it is a total derivative? What is it? And what gives us an ability to then write (as an example):

$$\int_0^x d(e^{-t^2}y) = e^{-x^2}y - y $$ without actually specifying what we are integrating with respect to? And why can we do the above anyway?

Comment: I think it's just a computational trick. In your example, somebody must have told before that the integration variable is $t$. Otherwise I could equally well have written $\int_0^x d(e^{-{t^2}}y)=e^{-{t^2}}x$. This inconsistency shows that there is no intrinsic meaning in this writing.

Comment: Actually, $$\int_0^x d(e^{-t^2}y(t)) = e^{-x^2}y(x) - y(0). $$